# Assigning background images to list items with JS

Tags: javascript, html, parameters

I'm trying to assign background images to the list items in my ul with JS.
I have all the images named with ascending numbers, corresponding to the id and calling parameter of the onload() function in the li.
I've written the function to change the background image and called the function when the window loads with window.onload
But for some reason it's all not working, would really appreciate if someone could help me out :)

```
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <header>
        <h1 class="wordmark">PROJECT KATANA</h1>
    </header>
    <section id="main">
        <ul class="playlist">
            <li class="track" id="1" onload="bgImage('1')">Title <span>- Artist</span></li>
            <li class="track" id="2" onload="bgImage('2')">Title <span>- Artist</span></li>
            <li class="track" id="3" onload="bgImage('3')">Title <span>- Artist</span></li>
            <li class="track" id="4" onload="bgImage('4')">Title <span>- Artist</span></li>
        </ul>
    </section>
</div>
```

```
<script>
function bgImage(number) {
    var pathStart = 'url(../project-katana/sources/images/';
    var ending = '.jpg)';
    var pathFull = pathStart + number + ending;
    var vElement = document.getElementById(number);

    vElement.style.backgroundImage = pathFull;
}

window.onload = function () {
    bgImage(number);
};
```

Comment: Your `onload` on `li` will not get fired. You will have to fetch them and process them. [JSFiddle - Sample](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/0wLhc3z6/)

Comment: onload event fires only for few elements 'li' is not one of them ref -https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp

Comment: Thanks @Rajesh , it worked that way !